# Mongo Db and Spring

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, nosql

I want to work on Mongo DB with Spring 3. Is there any simple application and tutorial based on that application that I can follow to learn it?

Comment: Have you tried this tutorial: http://krams915.blogspot.com/2011/02/spring-data-mongodb-tutorial.html. I have also started from this tutorial.

Comment: @rizzz86 voting up because actually answer is yours. It expands Spring tutorial's example, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Travel straight into the Spring Mongo [official tutorial with examples](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-document/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.core)

Comment: don't get me wrong but I think that spring official tutorials are the worst. I hope that they start fixing them soon together with their sample application because they make adopting spring way harder than it should be...

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this? 
http://java.dzone.com/articles/build-spring-data-project
more can be found here http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-document/docs/current/reference/html/